# jsLint Aptana jquery regex validation

Tags: jquery, regex, aptana, jslint

I'm trying to get JSLint to ignore the following jquery related errors ('$' is not defined), what would be the regex that I would need to add in Apatana's javascript validation filter to make this possible.

Or is there a completely different way to approach the issue.

Many thanks,

Clara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add global directive (to the JS file) and JSLint will ignore them: `/*global $*/`