# Can Aptana recognize variables/functions defined in other files?

Tags: javascript, symfony1, symfony-1.4, aptana

I'm using Aptana as my IDE while developing a Symfony (1.4) site. I have multiple JS files linked to each page (one with layout-specific scripts and one with page specific scripts.). When I edit these files individually, how can I tell Aptana that certain variables and functions are defined in other files? With the amount of "X is not defined" warnings that it is throwing, I'm not able to see the real errors/warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6653171/jslint-aptana-jquery-regex-validation) helped me with getting the jQuery 'bling' warnings out of the way. In your case it might be a bit cumbersome to include a lot of global directives in each js file though.

Comment: Thanks. I decided to go back to to Sublime Text so I'm going to accept your answer since it was the only one